# screen rotation and responsiveness with bootstrap

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using bootstrap to display some thumbnails in a div. The thumbnails are actually canvas because I need to create lighter thumbnails client-side.

It actually isn't perfect design (I am more a developer than a designer) but it works pretty well.

However I wonder about the following: when I look at the app with a mobile, in portrait mode, then I get the col-xs-6 class, and the screen looks fine. But when I rotate the screen, it appears I still get the col-xs-6 and its associated pixel size - which looks pretty ugly - screenshots:

rotated screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV9cj.jpg

normal screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsyM3.jpg

Is this a bug on the phone, or on the phone's browser (using Galaxy S3)- or is my code wrong? Shouldn't rotating the browser give a different resolution? Should I just ignore this issue, as maybe there's no elegant solution?
This is the HTML:

```
<div id="upload-list">
   <!-- for each image -->
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
     <div class="thumbnail">
       <div class="caption">IMG_0004.JPG<i><br>6.14 MB</i></div>
       <div style="display: none;" class="abort_upload working">
         <span class="alert-warning glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
       </div>
       <!-- This is for upload progress display -->
       <div class="knob-outer">
          <div class="knob-progress">
            <div style="display:inline;width:64px;height:64px;">
              <canvas height="64" width="64"></canvas>
              <input style="width: 36px; height: 21px; position: absolute; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: 21px; margin-left: -50px; border: 0px none; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; font: bold 12px Arial; text-align: center; color: rgb(7, 136, 165); padding: 0px;" readonly="readonly" value="0" data-width="64" data-height="64" data-fgcolor="#0788a5" data-readonly="1" data-bgcolor="#3e4043" type="text">
           </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <!-- the actual canvas with the image, is being generated client-side after file selection -->
       <canvas class="canvas-thumbnail" height="518" width="691"></canvas>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
@media (min-width: $screen-xs-min) {
  .thumbnail canvas.canvas-thumbnail { height:72px !important; width: 96px !important}
  .knob-progress {width: 64px; height: 64px}
}
$screen-xs:                  420px !default;
$screen-xs-min:              $screen-xs !default;
```

EDIT: other screen size css

```
$screen-sm:                  768px !default;
$screen-sm-min:              $screen-sm !default;

$screen-md:                  992px !default;
$screen-md-min:              $screen-md !default;

@media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) {
  .thumbnail canvas.canvas-thumbnail { height:64px !important; width: 86px !important}
}

@media (min-width: $screen-md-min) {
  .thumbnail canvas.canvas-thumbnail { height:95px !important; width: 126px !important}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two other screen resolution. You must handle all.
e.g. you have resolution: 800x600 but if you rotate phone you now have 600x800.
You must see thresholds in bootstrap about width and handle.

Comment: In your case this is 720x1280. And if you rotate phone this is 1280x720

Comment: n my opinion you must check type of your device (e.g check name/type of operation system) because you have normal desktop width if you rotate your phone.

Comment: I *do* have more CSS, please check my EDIT in the post. What really puzzles me though is that when I rotate the screen, as you can see in the screenshot, it picks col-xs-6 - NOT col-md-3 or even col-sm-3 (check the HTML), which should apply if the screen size is now desktop???

Comment: You can use java script to check this. Java script can return operating system for your css - when operating system = xyz you must set your styles. Not on change width - actualy not working this case because we have on mobile desktop resolution.

Comment: You can use java script to check this. Java script can return operating system for your css - when operating system = xyz you must set your styles. Not on change width - actualy not working this case because we have on mobile desktop resolution. Bootstrap dont have code to check this, jQuery have this. If you use bootstrap you myst use jQuery to good working bootstrap.

Comment: No. You must only handle operating system in jQuery and use css classess in case mobile or desktop.